# Django Multiple GET requests in one single view

Tags: python, django

In my django app, in the index page it always recieved 2 get requests (same user who logged in).
I noticed it when I'm looking in the command prompt. How can I handle that cause when it querying a model (that model is randomly generated) it query different item so that the system that I made is always broke!

Comment: Hi! Give more details including the index page's html, view, console messages etc.

Comment: Could you please show us the queries you are seeing in the command prompt?

Comment: Everything is ok now, I just set the attribute of link icon to it's path and not a "#"